# char[] into ascii and decimal value (double) java

Tags: java, char, ascii

based on this array :

```
final char[] charValue = { 'u', ' ', '}','+' };
```

i want to print the double value and the ascii value from it in Java. 
i can't find a proper solution for that in internet. I just found how to convert a single Character into Integer value. But what about many characters? 
the main problem is, i have a large char[] and some double and int values are stored in. for double values they are stored within 4 bytes size and integer 1 or 2 bytes so i have to read all this and convert into double or integer.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

When java was designed, there was C `char` being used for binary bytes and text.

Java made a clear separation between binary data (`byte[], InputStream/OutputStream`) and Unicode text (`char, String, Reader/Writer`). Hence Java has full Unicode support. The binary data, `byte[]`, need information: their used encoding, in order to be convertable to text: `char[]/String`.

In Java a `char[]` will rarely be used (as in C/C++), and it seems `byte[]` is intended, as you mention 4 elements to be used for an `int` etcetera. A char is 16 bits, containing UTF-16 text.

For this case one can use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) either wrapping a `byte[]` or being taken from a memory mapped file.

***Writing***

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(13); // 13 bytes
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // Intel order
buf.putInt(42);          // at 0
buf.putDouble(Math.PI);  // at 4
buf.put((byte) '0');     // at 12
buf.putDouble(4, 3.0);   // at 4 overwrite PI
byte[] bytes = buf.array();
```

***Reading***

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // Intel order
int a = buf.getInt();
double b = buf.getDouble();
byte c = buf.get();
```